# unit test a interface implementation with mock in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a simple unit test for a service in Spring Boot.

The service calls a method on a repository which returns an instance of User.
I'm trying to mock the repository, because I want to test only the service.

So, the code for **Repository**:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
  User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Service interface**:

```
public interface UserService {
  @Async
  CompletableFuture<User> findByEmail(String email) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

**Service implementation**:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  // dependency injection
  // don't need Autowire here
  // https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html
  public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<User> findByEmail(String email) throws InterruptedException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(user);
  }
}
```

**Unit Test**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  UserService userService;

  @Mock
  UserRepository mockUserRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void mustReturnUser() throws InterruptedException {
    String emailTest = "foo@bar.com";

    User fakeUser = new User();
    fakeUser.setEmail(emailTest);

    when(mockUserRepository.findByEmail(emailTest)).thenReturn(fakeUser);

    User user = userService.findByEmail(emailTest).join();
    assertThat(user).isEqualTo(fakeUser);

    verify(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(emailTest);
  }
}
```

When I run this test, I got a `MockitoException`:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'userService'.
...
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: the type 'UserService' is an interface.
```

Instead of using the interface, I tried to use the real implementation; changing the test like this:

```
@InjectMocks
UserServiceImpl userService;
```

Now, the test passes with success, but this don't appear be right (at least for me).
I like to test the UserService that Spring Boot is using (suppose that in a new version of my system, I implement a new UserServicePostgreSQLImpl - now I'm using MongoDB).
(edit: see the bottom edit in the question)

I changed the Unit Test as follows:

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
UserService userService;
```

but now I got a test failure:

```
Expected :model.User@383caf89
Actual   :null
```

For some reason, when I use `@Autowired`, the `UserRepository` mock doesn't work.
If I change the `emailTest` to use a real email in my database,
the test passes.
When I use `@Autowired`,
the test is using the real `UserRepository` and not a `Mock` version of `UserRepository`.

Any help?

Edit: looking at the answers from @msfoster and @dunni, and thinking better, I believe that the correct way is to test every implementation (in my example, use `UserServiceImpl userService`).

Comment: You're not testing the actual implementation, is that what you're saying?
The entire point is to test your implementation of the Interface.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm saying! I can test the real implementation if in test I use `UserServiceImpl userService`, but if I create another userService implementation, I will need to write a new unit test (ok, this is seens be correctly too), but I like to test only the implementation that Spring is using

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? Seems like the intention of the test is not to test the service, but an aspect of Your Application.

Comment: You want to unit test the implementation. If you add a `UserServicePostgreSQLImpl` later, you add another unit test for that class as well. If you want to write an integration test, which does Dependency Injection like at runtime, don't use `@InjectMocks`, but only `@Inject` or `@Autowired`, to inject the implementation into your test class. You can then use `@MockBean` to add a mock for your repository into the Spring context.

Comment: @msfoster and dunni , yes, both are right. thinking better now, I have to test all implementations. This thing about unit test and integration test it's new for me! tks! (for me, this question can be closed!)

Answer (score 3):

In order for your UserServiceImpl to be autowired when annotating it with @InjectMocks then it needs to registered as a Spring bean itself. You can do this most simply by annotating your UserServiceImpl class with @Service.

This will ensure it is picked up by the component scan in your Spring boot configuration. (As long as the scan includes the package your service class is in!)

Comment: Sorry, I update my question. The class `UserServiceImpl` already has `@Service` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You are running your tests with `SpringRunner` but for mocks you don't really need spring context. Try following code

```
// Using mockito runner
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

  @Mock
  UserRepository mockUserRepository;

  // Mockito will auto inject mockUserRepository mock to userService via constructor injection
  @InjectMocks
  UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void mustReturnUser() throws InterruptedException {
    String emailTest = "foo@bar.com";

    User fakeUser = new User();
    fakeUser.setEmail(emailTest);

    when(mockUserRepository.findByEmail(emailTest)).thenReturn(fakeUser);

    User user = userService.findByEmail(emailTest).join();
    assertThat(user).isEqualTo(fakeUser);

    verify(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(emailTest);
  }
}
```

Comment: don't worked too... `Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'userService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance. However, I failed because: the type 'UserService' is an interface.`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation on the @Yogesh Badke answer.

Although you are using spring at runtime,
there is no need to use spring during the unit test.
Instead,
you can mock all the dependencies and set them to the mocks during test setup
(using reflection or setters, if you have them).

Here is some example code:

```
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

public class TestUserService
{
    private static final String VALUE_EMAIL = "test email value";

    private UserService classToTest;

    @Mock
    private User mockUser;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository mockUserRepository;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);

        classToTest = new UserService();

        doReturn(mockUser).when(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(VALUE_EMAIL);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
            classToTest,
            "userRepository",
            mockUserRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void findByEmail_goodEmailInput_returnsCorrectUser()
    {
        final User actualResult;


        actualResult = classToTest.findByEmail(VALUE_EMAIL);


        assertSame(
            mockUser,
            actualResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If interface is implemented by more than one class, then use the qualifier name (example below) in Junit beans.xml file  to run the respective Junit test case.

Example:

```
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("animal")
    private Animal animals;
```

In Junit beans.xml

```
  <bean id="animal" class="com.example.abc.Lion"/>
```

where Lion is the implementation class for the Interface Animal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `@InjectMocks` for the implementation class. Not the interface class.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {

  @Mock
  UserRepository mockUserRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl; ------> This is important
}
```